# Embedding customize sender view

Tags: docusignapi, envelope

We want to open sender view of draft/created envelope in our application using REST API and allow sender/user to add signature fields/tags in documents. This sender view currently shows and allow all the options where sender can add new recipient or modify, can change the document and etc. But we want to restrict sender to only can add/edit signature fields/tags, we do not want to allow user to modify any other envelope information or even can send from there.

In short words: Want to open sender view of envelope only for edit signatory fields/tags using REST API.

Could anyone help how we can achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can start the view on the tagging page by adding `send=1` to the API call. Eg:

```
https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/{account_id}/envelopes/{envelope_id}/views/sender?send=1
```

However the user can still go back to the recipients page if they want to by using the "Other Actions" menu item.

An alternative is for you to figure out what your users need to do on the tagging page and do it for them programmatically. That way you're both providing a better user experience for them and you don't have to worry about them changing the recipients or documents.

What are they doing on the tagging pages? It is not hard for you to programmatically place the tags by using anchor field locating. See the [recipe](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/recipes/autoplace).

Comment: Thanks for the help but we don't want anchor field tagging